# Could you please check if this substitution is right so far?

Tags: algorithm, math, equation, substitution, recurrence

> The question:
>
> Use resubstitution to solve the following recurrence equation:
>
> T(N) = 2T(n-1) + n; n >=2 and T(1) = 1

So far I have this:

T(n) = **2T(n-1) + n**

= 2(2T(n-2) + (n-1)) + n

= **4T(n-2) + 3n -2**

= 2(4T(n-3) + 3(n-1) -2) + n

= 2(4T(n-3) + 3n -3 -2) + n

= 2(4T(n-3) + 3n -5) + n

= 8T(n-3) + 6n - 10 + n

= **8T(n-3) +7n -10**

I'm just wondering if so far, the way I'm approaching this is correct.
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This step is wrong:

```
= 4T(n-2) + 3n -2

= 2(4T(n-3) + 3(n-1) -2) + n
```

It should be

```
= 4T(n-2) + 3n -2

= 4(2T(n-3) + (n-2)) + 3n - 2
```

You replace the `T(n-i)` by `2T(n-i-1) + (n-i)`.

Apart from that, I think you're getting this wrong. What your teacher wants you to do, is to *feel* what the value of `T(n)` will be. In this case, you see that each time you iterate, you multiply the first coefficient by `2`, and you have at the end a member like `an+b`. This means that `T(n) = 2^n + O(n)` because only the biggest member matters.